# Are circular symlinks harmless?

Tags: bash, symlink

There's a bug in my project's build system that creates lots of circular symlinks for many different directories.

Basically we are doing `ln -sf <src_dir> <target_dir>` for many directories every time we run a build.

Although this is clearly a bug, I don't see any issues happening because of this.

So are circular symlinks harmless? Or are there scenarios where they can create problems?

Comment: Why I think this question is suitable for stack overflow? - Although the question doesn't seem directly related to programming, there can be programming scenarios where circular symlinks can create a problem.